# Basic array looping in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't loop?

If I pre napIncident it gives null.

My code

```
  <tr ng-repeat="napIncident in vm.NapIncidents">
                            <pre>{{vm.NapIncidents | json}}</pre>
                            <td>
                                {{napIncident.Incident}}
                            </td>
```

Pre output

```
[
  {
    "NapIncident": {
      "Incident": "Zahlunsverbindungen ändern",
      "IncidentID": "0002724285",
      "NapID": "4214",
      "NapStatus": "erfasst",
      "Username": "silvat",
      "NumberOfApprovers": "2",
      "RecordDate": "12-12-2018",
      "CheckerInformationList": [
        {
          "CheckerInformation": {
            "Checker": "silvat",
            "Date": "21-09-2018",
            "TimeOfDay": "12:12:36",
            "CheckerInfo": "Something",
            "CheckerInfoText": "Something else"
          }
        }
      ],
      "Alterations": [
        {
          "Alteration": {
            "Field": "IBAN",
            "OldValue": "DE12345",
            "NewValue": "DE54321"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: your key is `NapIncident`, but you are using `Incident`. Change this line `{{napIncident.Incident}}` to `{{napIncident.NapIncident}}`

Comment: Any progress ...?

Answer (score 0):

When using `ng-repeat` you map each item to a temporary variable, and when you have an array of named literals i.e array of `NapIncident: {...}` you must refer to `NapIncident` as a property :

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in vm.NapIncidents">
  <td>
    {{ item.NapIncident.Incident }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ item.NapIncident.IncidentID }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you have to access to your item . In your case is napIncident. Check your html part you will find  ng repeat "NapIncident in vm.NapIncidents" .
To access to the details {{NapIncident.NapIncident.Incident}}